# Xamarin: set labelText with an instance of ViewModel isnt updating UI

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

I defined a Label in Xaml

```
<Label Text="{Binding DeviceGuid}"/>
```

set the BindingContext inside my Page

```
BindingContext = new BluetoothViewModel();
```

and wrote the code for the getter and setter in the ViewModel

```
private string _deviceGuid;
    public string DeviceGuid
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceGuid;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_deviceGuid != value)
            {
                _deviceGuid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

So thats the simple Thing :). The Binding works if I change the value inside the ViewModel.
Now here it comes:
There are some Backgroundtasks (or just other classes) that, in my opinion, should have Access to that property and if they will write it, the UI should update automatically. 
I think its bad practice but I dont know how to realise it different.
I´ve already tried to create another instance of the viewmodel like

```
BluetoothViewModel a = new BluetoothViewModel();
a.DeviceGuid = "test";
```

Its calling the OnPropertyChanged() but isnt updating the UI ...
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
BluetoothViewModel a = new BluetoothViewModel();
a.DeviceGuid = "test";
```

You are creating another instance of the viewmodel that is not the one in your BindingContext.

Do this instead:

```
public BluetoothViewModel viewmodel;
BindingContext = viewmodel= new BluetoothViewModel();
```

And then:

```
viewmodel.DeviceGuid = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it must be happening is that you are not making these changes in the `MainThread` which is the thread responsible for making changes on the UI.

Do something like below where you change the property data:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
DeviceGuid="New string"; });
```

### Update

What you should be doing is using the BindingContext and creating a new instance so your   variable 'a' should look something like below

```
private BluetoothViewModel viewmodel;
BindingContext = viewmodel= new BluetoothViewModel  ();
```

And then do this

```
 viewmodel.DeviceGuid="New string";
```

Comment: That did not the Trick for me :( I tried Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    BluetoothViewModel.instance.DeviceGuid = "New string";
                    BluetoothViewModel.instance.DeviceState = "New string";
                });

Comment: No it did Not ;(

Comment: Updated my answer take a look